# Configure Service Reference... - Object reference is not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, local

I am working with `Visual Studio 2013`, `.NET4.5`.

Originally I was WCF service consumer but due to lack of resources in team that deals with subsystem I took over development of both sides of WCF service. So I got Code of the WCF service that I need to call and now trying to plug it in to debug it on my local system.

Issue: Service that I need to call works on localhost fine I can get wsdl and browse to it.

[image]
However when I try in `Visual Studio 2013` 'Configure Service Reference...' and Try to change url from dev server to local it gives me `Object reference is not set to an instance of an object` error.

[image]

**Has anyone experienced something similar?
What is causing this?
How do I fix it?**

Comment: Can you please show your code as a text? And [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @SonerGönül There is no code, I am trying to configure using Visual Studio UI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved myself by deleting Service Reference, and then adding new Service Reference with given URL.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit late but I had a similar problem and I fixed it by adding
an **identity** element to the app.config file for the service's endpoint. Example:

```
<identity>
  <userPrincipalName value="username@domain" />
</identity>
```

The for me it worked even with an empty value for **userPrincipalName**:

```
<identity>
  <userPrincipalName value="" />
</identity>
```

Full endpoint element:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9876/my-service/tcp" ... >
  <identity>
    <userPrincipalName value="" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```